# javascript ajax POST issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I am a problem with simple javascript web page hosted on AWS S3 that makes a HTTP POST to AWS API Gateway using ajax.

I am able to make a call using curl with success:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ankieta --data @data.json`

data.json file:

`{ "imie": "jasiu",
   "ocena": "6",
   "opinia": "niezle"
}`

My javascript code looks like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<title>Ankieta</title>

<h1>Wypelnik ankiete</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="uruchom()">JSON</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function uruchom() {
    var resultDiv = $("#resultDivContainer");
    var myData = {"imie": "Michal"};
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ankieta",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("zonk");
            }

        });
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the error I get from web debug:
`GET https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ankieta?callback=jQuery17203000220305941388_1546897907447&{%22imie%22:%22Michal%22}&_=1546897908872 net::ERR_ABORTED 400`

It looks like there is problem with callback and in the URL is altered with my data from body. In my case I don't want to check whenever the callback is fine - want to simply POST data.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your getting an issue because your server is saying you are sending a bad request. Your json file and the myData variable are different, you sure you aren't missing those 2 parameters that you show from your curl?

Comment: I tried that already. Even with the same myData as from data.json file, getting the same error :(

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a reply header, not a request header. There's no point in putting it in `$.ajax`.

Comment: You can't use `dataType: 'jsonp'` with `type: "POST"`.

Answer (score 1):

POST can't be used to send a JSONP request. JSONP doesn't actually use AJAX, it works by creating a `<script>` tag whose `src` is the URL. There's no way to send POST data this way, so the `data` is added as URL parameters.

If this API expects the JSON in POST data, you can't use `dataType: 'jsonp'`. You have to use `dataType: 'json'`. If the API doesn't allow CORS, you'll need to use a proxy on your server to make the actual request, you can't do it directly from the browser.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right I should use "dataType: json". CORS on API is enabled, but that made me thinking and I checked AWS Lambda behind API and there was an errror, as I didn't return "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

Answer (score 0):

Dont stringify the data object. JQuery does this for you. Just pass object.

```html
var myData = {"imie": "Michal"};
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/ankieta",
            type: "POST",
            data: myData,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("ok");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("zonk");
            }

        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to send data using this format:   "data: JSON.stringify(myData),"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions and answers especially in CORS direction. I was sure my API GW has CORS enabled, but didn't check AWS Lambda that is behind it and found that I was not returning "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header back to client.

`exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": { 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" 
        }
    });
};`

After applying this, I can send HTTP POST.